'Exclude' slicer in Power BI
I want to create an 'exclude' slicer in power bi to filter and display records that do not have the slicer selected values in my visuals.
Sample dataset :

Slicer selection :

If I select 'FD' in my slicer, only OrderID: B456, C789, D111 that do not have the 'FD' StatusCode will show up in my matrix visual.
I tried these codes in my measure but it does not work.
FilterOrderIDs =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        dataset,
        NOT (
            CONTAINSSTRING (
                'dataset'[StatusCode],
                SELECTEDVALUE ( 'dataset'[StatusCode] )
            )
        )
    )
)


Table 2 = DISTINCT('Table'[StatusCode])

and do not create relationship between these two tables
then create a measure
MEASURE =
VAR _list =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        DISTINCT ( 'Table'[StatusCode] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[OrderID] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table 2'[StatusCode] ) IN _list, 0, 1 )

and add this measure to the visual filter and set to 1


you can try this to count the order number
MEASURE 2=
DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[OrderID] )
    - CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[OrderID] ),
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[StatusCode] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table 2'[StatusCode] )
        )
    )



Thank you. This solution gives me the expected result. However I have a card visual that counts the number of orders displayed in the table visual. The distinct count of OrderID  does not change with the Exclude Slicer selection. How do I create a measure tor the card visual to show 3 instead of  5 orders based on the exclude slicer selection?

I have updated my answer. Pls have a try.

@Amira, Fantastic! My card visual is now giving me the correct order count using the measure in your answer. Thank you so much for all your help and sharing.

For this to work, your slicer cannot be using the same table as your data table.
Create a new Calculated Table with:
Dim StatusCode = DISTINCT('dataset'[StatusCode])

And use this one for your slicer. Then update your measure to:
FilterOrderIDs = 
  var slicerValues = DISTINCT('Dim StatusCode'[StatusCode])
  var orderIDs = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
      DISTINCT('dataset'[OrderID]),
      'dataset'[StatusCode] IN slicerValues
    )

  return 
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS('dataset'),
      NOT 'dataset'[OrderID] IN orderIDs,
      REMOVEFILTERS('Dim StatusCode')
    )


Thank you for your proposed solution. However it does not give me the expected result because it just excludes 'FD' StatusCode from the OrderIDs in the visual display. OrderID A123 and E222 with other StatusCode (OR, DO, AD) still display in the table visual.

Oops, I missed that detail in your question. I've updated the answer above to correct this miss.
